# How to lock div to the top of the page

Tags: jquery, css, backbone.js, haml

I am using haml to build my web app. In my page I have 2 sections, header and avatar thumbnails. I want to keep the header section locked at the top of the page but the rest of the page scrollable. How can I achieve this?

```
.standalone_thread_wrapper
  //I WANT TO FIX THIS SECTION AT TOP OF PAGE
  .page_section.header
    .text
      %h4
    .action
      %input.btn.primary.add_muse{type: "submit", value: "Add Muse"}
    .clear
  .page_section.avatar_thumbnails
    %a{href: "#", rel: "tooltip", title: "See all muses", nickname: "All"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use fixed position CSS for `.page_section.header`. See below,

```
.page_section.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px; 
}
```